# BB10 Android App updates clearing user data

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I am porting an Android app for BlackBerry and during tests I see my saved user data (properties and a list of activities) disapearing each time I upload my newly build BAR to the device.
Will this happen on every update of the app?
On Android, my local data stays permanently on uploading and installing new versions.
I do not want to use shared storage for this data to avoid too many permissions, since the user won't understand why I need this shared storage (user could wonder about if I want to steal his other data).

Comment: I've been seeing this as well. Have you seen this happening in the wild on production builds?

Comment: @PaulLammertsma Well, App is to be published soon, but not yet ready. So I do not have any experience "in the wild".

Comment: We're launching our first update soon. I'll try to remember to follow up on this when I get the opportunity to test it. Drop me a line if I forget.

Comment: Hello, have you any news about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue of the Android VM version used at that specific time. In the meantime, the behaviour is as one would expect it, and all user data stays even after app update.